# How to invoke a function by string name in python?

Tags: python

```
# funcs.py
def foo():
    print('invoked')

# main.py
import funcs
name = 'foo'
funcs.name()  # doesn't work
```

How to invoke a function that is dynamically selected and the name is stored in a string?

Comment: Could you not just use `eval`? Like `eval('foo()')`.

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi indeed it does. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
eval(name + "()")
```

Like This

```
#funcs
def foo():
    print('invoked')

# main.py
from funcs import foo
name = 'foo'
eval(name + "()")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But it seems less safe than the highly upvoted `getattr(module, funcname)()`. I mean I kind of trust my input strings but an `eval()` is too allmighty.